# Download AOSP android-4.4.4_r2 using repo

Tags: android, git, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source, repo

I am looking to download a specific version of android source code - android-4.4.4_r2. I followed the instructions provided on the "Downloading the Source" page of android source and used repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.4_r2. And when I execute repo sync, it looks like the entire tree is getting downloaded. The current directory size of the download is 54G and is continuing to grow.

I am trying to fulfill the system requirement, as per instructions on https://github.com/huz123/GemDroid_QEMU.

Is there a different to way to download just the android-4.4.4_r2?
Or is it supposed to download the entire tree the first time (>54G)?
Please help me with the situation. Thank you!

Comment: `repo sync -c`. `-c, --current-branch` fetch only current branch from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!** the [official documentation](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) of hardware requirements is:

> At least 100GB of free disk space for a checkout, 150GB for a single build, and 200GB or more for multiple builds. If you employ ccache, you will need even more space.

When working on the full OS system you'll have to handle **large** amount of data - the `repo sync` command can take you more than 5 hours and it's normal.
The `make` command that builds and compiles your project can also take some several hours on first time.

Answer (score 0):

Step to download android source code(AOSP) in Ubuntu

1. First create one folder like "aosp-m" to copy AOSP code in your machine.
2. Open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and change your Dir to latest created Dir let say "aosp-m"
3. After that Run the following command in terminal :- 

   `git clone git://gitz01/cm/download/android/manifest`
4. Run Following command in terminal one by one

   `git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`
5. then run following command for repo init

   `repo init -u git://gitz01/cm/download/android/manifest -b master -m identifiedmanifest.xml`

   here you can replace `identifiedmanifest.xml` to your desired AOSP source code , Let Say `android-6.0.1_r10.xml` marshmellow.
6. and in the last run `repo sync` command. This command start downloading your desired  AOSP code in your machine. This opertation take more than 1 hours(depending on your internet connection speed) to download source code.

Thats it... Happy Coding.......